# Como setar o valor de um dropdown (primeNg) pegando apenas uma propriedade do objeto

Tags: angular, primeng

Criei um campo do tipo dropdown onde quero enviar somente um número como valor do select. Mas para listar as `options` do dropdown criei um objeto name: string, id: number para poder renderizar o name na tela.
Gostaria de receber como value somente este id do objeto. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

form.component.ts:

```
interface ITemplatePDF {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

  public templates_pdf: ITemplatePDF[];
  public selectedTemplatePDF: ITemplatePDF;

    this.templates_pdf = [
      { name: "Sem condições", id: 1 },
      { name: "Max. 2 condições", id: 2 },
      { name: "Max. 5 condições", id: 3 },
      { name: "5+ condições", id: 4 },
    ];
```

form.component.html:

```
<p-dropdown
   formControlName="template_pdf"
   optionLabel="name"
   [options]="templates_pdf"
   [(ngModel)]="selectedTemplatePDF"
    placeholder="Selecione o template da tabela PDF"
 >
</p-dropdown>
```

OBS: vi na documentação do primeNg que agora da pra por uma prop `optionValue`que resolveria meu problema, mas esse é um projeto antigo e complexo que ta usando a v8.2.14, e se atualizar quebra vários componentes.
Alguém já passou por isso e tem alguma solução?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode formatar o objeto no formato que o primeNG espera {label, value}. Sendo o `label` indicando o nome que aparecerá no campo, e `value` o valor de retorno.

```
this.templates_pdf = [
      { label: "Sem condições", value: 1 },
      { label: "Max. 2 condições", value: 2 },
      { label: "Max. 5 condições", value: 3 },
      { label: "5+ condições", value: 4 },
    ]
```